# Create New Relic SLI for AWS Lambda

Tags: newrelic

I want to monitor aws lambda. Hence want to create service levels first (SLI and SLO). The metrics to be used for service levels are : lambda errors and lambda invocations.
I am using this query for valid response :
SELECT count(*) FROM AwsLambdaInvocation WHERE `error` = true TIMESERIES 5 minute

and for bad response :
FROM AwsLambdaInvocation SELECT count(*) WHERE `error` = true TIMESERIES 5 minutes

But this does not let me create s service level indicating the error "invalid Where clause".
I think it is probably because of the keyword "TIMESERIES" but not sure

any idea about this !!

I am using this query for valid response :
SELECT count(*) FROM AwsLambdaInvocation WHERE `error` = true TIMESERIES 5 minute

and for bad response :
FROM AwsLambdaInvocation SELECT count(*) WHERE `error` = true TIMESERIES 5 minutes